# The inline button in telegram bot does not work

Tags: python

I encountered a problem, ***after pressing one of the buttons another menu appears, but there is no answer from them**, there is no error in the terminal P.S if you just send a message, then everything is okay

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['groups'])
def get_group(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    fes11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фес-11', callback_data='fes11')
    fes12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фес-12', callback_data='fes12')
    fes13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фес-13', callback_data='fes13')
    markup.add(fes11, fes12, fes13)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<i>Обери свою</i><b> групу</b>', reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def fes13(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'fes13':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            m = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Monday', callback_data='m')
            markup.add(m)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Pick the day of week:', reply_markup=markup)#the button appears, however next callback didn`t work

            @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call1: True)
            def otvet(call1):
                if call.message:
                    if call.data == 'm':
                        bot.send_message(call1.message.chat.id, fes_13[f'{monday}'])
```

there is container:

```
monday = calendar.day_name[0]
tuesday = calendar.day_name[1]
wednesday = calendar.day_name[2]
thursday = calendar.day_name[3]
friday = calendar.day_name[4]
fes_13 = {'Monday': {'2\ufe0f\u20e3 - Вища Математика(Зеліско Г.В) 10:10 - 11:30\n3\ufe0f\u20e3 - Алг. та структури даних(Вельгош С.Р) 11:50 - 13:10\n4\ufe0f\u20e3 - ООП(Злобін Г.Г) 13:30 - 14:50'},
         'Tuesday': {'3\ufe0f\u20e3 - ООП(Злобін Г.Г) 11:50 - 13:10\n4\ufe0f\u20e3Іноземна мова(-) 13:30 - 14:50\n5\ufe0f\u20e3 Фізвиховання(-) 15:05 - 16:25'},
         'Wednesday': {'2\ufe0f\u20e3(друга група) - Алгоритми та стурктури даних(Кучеренко O.I) 10:10 - 11:30\n3\ufe0f\u20e3 - Вища математика(Петрук Т.М) 11:50 - 13:10\n4\ufe0f\u20e3 - Іноземна Мова(-) 13:30 - 14:50\n5\ufe0f\u20e3(Перша група) Алгоритми та структури даних(Кучеренко О.І) 15:05 - 16:25'},
         'Thursday': {'1\ufe0f\u20e3 - Українська мова(Кметь І.Ф) 8:30 - 9:50\n2\ufe0f\u20e3 - Управління ІТ проектами(Каськун О.Д) 10:10 - 11:30\n3\ufe0f\u20e3 - Вища математика(Петрук Т.М) 11:50 - 13:10'},
         'Friday': {'1\ufe0f\u20e3 - Українська мова(Сокіл М.Б) 8:30 - 9:50\n2\ufe0f\u20e3 - Вища математика(Зеліско Г.В) 10:10 - 11:30\n3\ufe0f\u20e3 - Управління ІТ проектами(Ненчук Т.М) 11:50 - 13:30'}
         }
```

Comment: the code as it stands is not sufficeint to reproduce the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L, now, i think is normal